# How to query post types like faq from wordpress site using wordpress rest api

Tags: json, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I am working on an application which needs its data from another website. The website i want to query has been made in wordpress so i am using wordpress rest api.
The website has a plugin installed Quick and Easy FAQs. Using this plugin the owner of the site has add a couple of questions. Which i need to fetch.
I just cant figure out what the url to use to fetch it. For a normal post i used.

https://mysitename.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/ and it is working but when i try 
https://mysitename.com/wp-json/wp/v2/types/ i get only these types not faq.
  "post"
  "page": 
  "attachment" 
  "feedback"
   "jp_pay_order"
  "jp_pay_product"
So i was wondering anyone know how i can fetch faqs.